# Files present in .gitignore always get added to git after building Android Project in Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: git, gitignore, android-studio-3.2

I have updated android studio from `3.0.0` to `3.3.2`. Everytime I build project files like `.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser` and `.idea/caches/gradle_models.ser` get added to git. This files are already present in `.gitignore`.This is my Project level .gitignore file

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/tasks.xml
/.idea/misc.xml
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/vcs.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
/.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
/.idea/caches/gradle_models.ser
.externalNativeBuild
```

What changes need to be done in project to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 2):

Please change the .gitignore file as follows. You are telling it to find the files in the `root` location.With below configuration, it will look in the project directory. This should resolve the issue.

```
*.iml
.gradle
local.properties
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/libraries
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
.DS_Store
build
captures
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
.idea/caches/gradle_models.ser
.externalNativeBuild
```

You will have to delete the files from the git cache and re-commit.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if those files are not already tracked with:

```
git rm --cached .idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
git rm --cached .idea/caches/gradle_models.ser
```

If you can remove those files, then (commit and) they will be ignored

Check they are ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- .idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```